# Linq Remove results with ALL statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hi I'm trying to use Linq to remove "all" entities from a list.

Problem: I'm searching for users that have certain certificates in my database. Thing is that it returns them row by row.... But what I need to check is: If the user holds all the required certificates. This should be checked against my int array.

This is my array: [3,5,16], now I want to delete all user who does not have all three of those from the list. Name of the array in code is **mandatory**!

The listitems I get back looks like this

listitem.CertificateValue 
listitem.Uid
listitem.NameOfPerson

So basicly for this example Peter has **three rows** in the list, in this case all the rows needed to stay in the list. But Philip only has 2 rows and hence both of these should be deleted since he does not fullfill the total search criteria.

Also copyOfMandatoryis just to not mess with the original collection and cause an expection(collection size changed).

```
foreach (var item in copyOfMandatory)
{
    if (!mandatoryusers.All(i => mandatory.Contains(i.CertificateValue) 
                            || i.Uid == item.Uid))
    {
         mandatoryusers.RemoveAll(i => i.Uid == item.Uid);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
RemoveAll works like a charm it the if statement that does not work as expected.

Doing this it does not take away any part of the list, I began wiht && instead of || but whne doing that it kills everything but the last person it encounters as long as he/she fullfills the search criteria.

Anyone have a hint on how to do this?

Comment: Is `mandatory` your array of required certificates, i.e. `[3, 5, 16]`?

Comment: yes sorry for being unclear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like that

```
var uIdToRemove = mandatoryusers.GroupBy(m => m.Uid)
                    .Where(g => mandatory.Except(g.Select(s => s.CertificateValue)).Any())
                    .Select(g => g.Key).ToList();

mandatoryusers.RemoveAll(x => uidToRemove.Contains(x.Uid));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if `All` criteria is off.

```
if (!mandatoryusers.All(i => mandatory.Contains(i.CertificateValue) 
                        || i.Uid == item.Uid))
{
     mandatoryusers.RemoveAll(i => i.Uid == item.Uid);
}
```

It needs to be with an `&&` not an `||` and you should call `Any()` instead of `All()`

```
if (!mandatoryusers.Any(i => mandatory.Contains(i.CertificateValue) 
                            && i.Uid == item.Uid))
{
    mandatoryusers.RemoveAll(i => i.Uid == item.Uid);
}
```

Hopefully I understood what your logic and question correctly.

Comment: Hi! Thanks I tried the && first but all it did was remove all but the last two rows from my list. As if it checked everything all the time, but when the two remaining it were just two it it let that pass.

Comment: @CarlPalsson I updated the answer. I realized you want any Any instead of an All for the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your `All` call is not granular enough: it is trying to ensure that ALL entries exist at all times... Not that all entries PER USER exist.

Try converting each entry to a dictionary:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<ItemType>>();
foreach (var mandatoryItem in mandatoryItems)
{
    List<ItemType> itemTypeValue = null;
    if (!dict.TryGetValue(mandatoryItem.Uid, out itemTypeValue)
    {
        itemTypeValue = new List<ItemType>();
        dict.Add(mandatoryItem.Uid, itemTypeValue);
    }
    itemTypeValue.Add(mandatoryItem);
}
```

Now you have all ItemType at the key of Uid. From here, use LINQ:

```
mandatoryusers = mandatoryusers.Where(i => dict[i.Uid].All(x => mandatory.Contains(x.CertificateValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement isn't correct (as you stated) - it's attempting to check whether all items contain a certificate with an id in `mandatory` **or** where the userid is the current item. What you should be doing is filtering by userid **first** and then checking the certificates. 
This isn't the way I would do it, though. I'd group the results by User and then check the certificates

```
var usersWithAllCertificates = mandatoryUsers.GroupBy(mu => mu.Uid)
             //Select the ones that have all 3 certificates
             .Where(g => g.Select(u => u.CertificateValue)
                 .Intersect(mandatory).Count() == 3)
             .Select(g => g.ToList());
```

The `Intersect` operator will combine the lists and the result will be the items that are the same in both lists. So, if the user has all 3 certificates (3, 5 and 16) the result of the intersect will be 3 items. The `usersWithAllCertificates` object will include all the users you want. This is explicitely selecting the values you want instead of removing the ones you don't want, which imo is a better way of going about it. Note that this assumes each user is only in the list once (i.e. only has 3 certificates)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus ha! You're right. I meant `Intersect`. Thanks!